# Value is changed just in methods, VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a value with `false` default value, and inside a watch  (for another value) I have chage it's value, but the value is changed just there, on second Click (event), the value is changed. Not sure why..
The value is change when I trigger that event twice..

```
<template>
   <h1>{{hide_confidence}}</h1> //HERE IS NOT CHANGED
</template>

...
  data() {
    return {
      mainSelect: '',
      hide_confidence: true
    };
  },
   watch: {
        mainSelect(value) {
            if (value !== "" && value !== "none") {
                this.hide_confidence = false;
                // this.confidence_score = "";
            } else {
                this.hide_confidence = true;
            }

            console.log("Value: ", this.hide_confidence);  //HERE IS CHANGED
        },

        hide_confidence(value{
            console.log("Value: ", value);  //HERE IS NOT CHANGED
        }
   }

...
```

Comment: What do you want to do here?
hide_confidence(value) is giving it's own value. That is `true` and mainSelect(value) is empty so it is going to `if` and changing the value of `hide_confidence`. If you want to change permanently then other issue. You have to call an event to do that.

Comment: `watch` is not a method to change your data permanently. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property

Comment: With computed it works, I am not sure that I understand why, but thank you. You can submit an answer, if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`watch` is not a method to change your data permanently. Just you can play with other properties with changing it temporary.

If you want to change a value permanently then you have to call an event.

Please take look in details here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property